# A central division algebra is not its commutator

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

In looking at old qualifying exam questions, I've come upon a question that has me stumped.

> Let $A$ be a central division algebra (of finite dimension) over a field $k$. Let $[A,A]$ be the $k$-subspace of $A$ spanned by the elements $ab-ba$ with $a, b \in A$. Show that $[A,A] \neq A$.

If $\text{char } k \nmid [A:k]$, there is a very pleasant argument at hand: fix a basis of $A$ and define $\text{tr}(r)$ to be the trace of the matrix associated to the vector space endomorphism $a \mapsto ra$. It's easily seen that $\text{tr}(ab-ba) = 0$; but by our assumption on the dimension, $\text{tr}(1) \neq 0$, so that $[A,A] \neq A$. This argument fails spectacularly in general. I'd like to salvage it, but I'm not convinced that's possible.

I would appreciate hints - if you give a full answer, I would appreciate it if you put it in spoiler boxes.

Comment: That the identity element in a normed algebra isn't a commutator was proved by Wielandt (see Rudin's *Functional Analysis*, theo.13.6). Maybe you could adapt it to your situation with the trace in place of a norm. The proof begins by assuming $xy-yx= 1$ followed by the induction hypothesis $x^ny - xy^n = nx^{n-1}\ne 0$.

Comment: Wielandt's proof is very short indeed.

Comment: I think that your argument is fine if you use the reduced trace in place of the 'naïve' trace.  The theorem on p. 12 of http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/algebras.pdf shows that the reduced trace is always a non-0 map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I googled the question verbatim and the first result had a solution to the problem. As it turns out, one should perhaps look at more than just StackExchange when hunting for solutions. Here's a slightly expanded version of the proof (under Problem 2 [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~iacoley/hw/algqual.pdf) near the start of the document):

Let $\bar k$ be the algebraic closure of $k$. Then $\bar k$ is trivially a simple division algebra over $k$. Consider $B = A \otimes_k \bar k$; there is a theorem (see, for instance, Lorenz and Levy, Algebra II, ch 29 theorem 7) that, if $A$ and $B$ are simple $k$-algebras, and at least one is central, then $A \otimes_k B$ is a simple $k$-algebra. In particular, this means that (because $A$ is central) $B$ is a simple $k$-algebra, thus a simple $\bar k$-algebra. In addition, because $A$ is finite-dimensional over $k$, so is $B$ over $\bar k$.

It is not hard to see that the only division algebra over an algebraically closed field is the field itself; so by the Artin-Wedderburn theorem $B \cong M_n(\bar k)$ for some $n$. Then $[A,A] \otimes_k \bar k = [B,B]$, and because in $M_n(\bar k),$ $[B,B]$ consists of the traceless matrices, $[B, B] \neq B$; so $[A, A] \neq A$.