# Let $A$ be a central division algebra (of finite dimension) over a field $k$. Show that $[A,A] \neq A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

I am looking at the post [A central division algebra is not its commutator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/904624/a-central-division-algebra-is-not-its-commutator) and I have a few questions regarding the proof that was provided in the answer.

1. Why is $A$ a simple $k$-algebra?

My first observation is that $A$ is Artinian because it is finite-dimensional. Then, I normally think about the Jacobson Radical being trivial to arrive at $A$ being semisimple. Are all *central division algebras* simple? Every time I Google central division algebra, it leads me to the [Wikipedia page for central simple algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_simple_algebra) but there is no discussion on my question so I think I am misunderstanding something fundamental.

2. Given that $B =A \otimes_k \overline{k}$ how do I see that $[B,B] = [A,A] \otimes_k \overline{k}$? I usually view adding and subtracting pure tensors to be completely abstract.

Comment: About the title question: Have you heard of the reduced trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a hint for the first question, consider what a two sided ideal might look like in your division algebra, is there anything in the setup that forces this to be a trivial ideal? (Let $x$ be in this ideal…)

For the second part, imagine you had picked a basis over $k$. Can you use this to build a generating set of this commutator subalgebra over both $k$ and $\bar{k}$?

Comment: So for (1), if I take an element of an ideal of our division algebra $x\in I \subset A$, we get that $xx^{-1} = x^{-1}x = 1 \in I$ so $I = A$. Thus, division algebras don't have any proper nontrivial ideals so it must be a field. Since fields are central simple algebras over itself we have proven (1).

Comment: For (2), if we say that $\{ a_1, \dots, a_n \}$ is a basis for $A$ over $k$, then $[A,A]$ is generated by $\{ a_i a_j - a_j a_i \}_{i,j=1}^n$ over $k$. I guess here is where I begin to lose intuition. I am thinking that $B = A \otimes_k \overline{k}$ has basis $\{ a_i \otimes 1 \}_{i=1}^n$ and so $[B,B]$ has basis $\{ a_ia_j \otimes 1 - a_j a_i \otimes 1 \}_{i,j=1}^n$ over $\overline{k}$ which exactly also generates $[A,A] \otimes_k \overline{k}$?

Comment: Yep, that’s correct for the first question! For the second, that’s nearly it, but these commutators need not be a basis, but they do generate. A general algebra lemma that might help is that if $\{e_i\}$ generate a left $R$ module $M$ for any ring, then $\{1\otimes e_i\}$ generate $S\otimes_R M$ as an $S$ module. You can prove this “by hand”, but it’s also a great exercise to utilise the left exactness of tensor product to prove this generation statement.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!